# Multilingual website: Search results only displaying my default language

Tags: search, multilingual

My Website is [www.clownatec.com](http://www.clownatec.com).
It has 2 languages: french and english.

I have an index.php file which redirects users to either index-fr.html or index-en.html depending on the browser language. It works properly to redirect. However, Google only displays my default language's (fr) meta title and description in the search results, no matter the browser language.

Any idea how I could fix this?

**Here is my index.php**

```
    <?php
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    switch ($lang){

case "en":
    //echo "PAGE EN";
    include("index-en.html");//include check session EN
    break;
case "fr":
    //echo "PAGE FR";
    include("index-fr.html");
    break;      
default:
    //echo "PAGE FR - Setting Default";
    include("index-fr.html");//include FR in all other cases of different lang detection
    break;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `depending on the browser language` - Don't assume Google bot to be a browser. It might not even render the Javascript files. Try fetching your website from terminal and see which language is served.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using "terminal". I tried fetching as Google with their webmaster but it fetches it in the right language.

My only problem is the language displayed in their search results

Comment: Show us your index.php. We're blind otherwise.

Comment: Hi Bibhas, here is my index.php, thanks for your input, I hope this is going to help

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't fetch your website right when you search for something. It has a bot that continuously keeps visiting your website and stores the fetched information. From the `index.php` file, it's quite obvious that the Google bot doesn't have `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` set to `en`. Hence it's going to the `default` clause of the the switch-case statement, and that's why it's storing the description of `index-fr.html` and showing it when someone searches for it.

If you want the english description to show up on Google search results, you have to make the `index-en.html` default.

You might also want to read [this](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales).

Comment: I know I can change the default language and have Google always displaying this one.

What I need is for Google to display my english meta title and description to the english users and display the french meta title and description for french users.

Comment: Google will crawl just one title, description and show that to everyone.